# add value to each element in row if row contains match

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a `dataframe df` of integers across 6 variables.

```
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
b <- c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
c <- c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
d <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
e <- c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
f <- c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f)

print(df)

  a b c d e f
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  0  2  2  1  0  0
5  0  2  2  1  0  0
6  1  3  3  2  1  1
7  1  3  3  2  1  1
8  1  3  3  2  1  1
```

I would like to add 1 to each row that contains a zero, resulting in:

```
 a b c d e f
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  1  3  3  2  1  1
5  1  3  3  2  1  1
6  1  3  3  2  1  1
7  1  3  3  2  1  1
8  1  3  3  2  1  1
```

I've been able to test if a row contains a zero with the following code, which adds a new column of "TRUE" or "FALSE".

```
df$cont0 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% "0"))
```

I thought I would this new value to then add 1 to reach row where df$cont0 == "TRUE"

```
ifelse(df$cont0 == "TRUE", df + 1, df)
```

This ends up creating a nested list that still does not perform the correct operation. I understand that `ifelse` is already vectorized, but other than that I'm not sure how to approach this issue. I am open to splitting apart the df into "TRUE" and "FALSE" conditions, then performing the operation on df$cont0 == "TRUE", but they need to be re-merged in the original order as the data are chronological and row order therefore matters. However I suspect there's an easier solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a logical index with `rowSums` on the logical matrix and use that as row index to add

```
i1 <- rowSums(df == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0
df[i1,] <- df[i1, ] + 1
```

-ouptut

```
> df
   a  b  c  d  e  f
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  1  3  3  2  1  1
5  1  3  3  2  1  1
6  1  3  3  2  1  1
7  1  3  3  2  1  1
8  1  3  3  2  1  1
```

---

Regarding the use of `ifelse` on a logical vector, it is related to the property of `ifelse` that it requires all the arguments to be of same length which is not met in the OP's case

Answer (score 1):

**Just try to get row index first :**

```
index <- rowIndex(af == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0
af[index,] <- af[index, ] + 1
```

It should work.